# String Format C# Small Negative Values

Tags: c#, string, format

Why does the following program not output the negative sign for the second line?

```
var smallpos = 3.65433E-005;
var smallneg = -3.65433E-005;

Console.WriteLine("{0} in F4 format with a width of 8 characters {1}",
                  smallpos,
                  smallpos.ToString("F4").PadLeft(8).Substring(0, 8));

Console.WriteLine("{0} in F4 format with a width of 8 characters {1}",
                  smallneg,
                  smallneg.ToString("F4").PadLeft(8).Substring(0, 8));
```

Using VS 2017 Professional 15.8.2 C# 7.2

Comment: What is the output you are getting and what you were expected?

Answer (score 3):

`-3.65433E-005` represents `-0.0000365433`.

The issue here is with `smallneg.ToString("F4")`. It only considers the first 4 places after the decimal point; since they're all 0 the negative sign is left out as -0 wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: You _could_ enforce it with a custom format, if I remember correctly, though.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've eliminated enough digits from the back, the remaining number will have a value of zero, at which point the existence of a "`-`" has no real meaning.

This can be understood quite intuitively by running the snippet below, which has a decreasing number provided for the [fixed-point specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString).

In the last line, that specifier is omitted, at that point [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits?view=netframework-4.7.2) decides the number of decimal places used (depending on the culture used):

```
var smallneg = -3.65433E-005;

Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F10")); // -0,0000365433
Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F9"));  // -0,000036543
Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F8"));  // -0,00003654
Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F7"));  // -0,0000365
Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F6"));  // -0,000037
Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F5"));  // -0,00004
Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F4"));  // 0,0000 <-- Zero --> (-0) == 0

Console.WriteLine(smallneg.ToString("F"));   // 0,00
```

Comment: _"at which point the existence of a "-" has no real meaning."_ I disagree with that. If you are aware that the displayed number has been rounded, then it would indicate the original (exact) number was < 0 ... - I don't know if there are in fact real life applications, where this would be interesting or important, but there is always a first time for everything.

Comment: @Fildor I see your point, but note that the resulting output of `smallneg.Tostring()` is not a number, but a string, and in the context of that string, any information about eliminated digits has already been lost.

Comment: Of course. Just saying it _could_ have a meaning if it was possible to have it. Though I admit in those cases you'd probably rather have the exact value than just a "hint" that the exact value was a tiny bit smaller than 0 ...